# Брать на («) слабо (»)

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, кавычки

Кавычки нужны?

`Брать на («) слабо (»).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-разному пишут: на слабо, на «слабо», «на слабо».

Вот, например, у одного автора в одном и том же произведении (Сергей Гандлевский. НРЗБ):

*Высоколобые ухари не просыхали, море казалось по колено, безобразничали по нарастающей, **беря** самих себя и друг друга **на слабо**;

Собственно, именно Аниному вызову, когда девушка в раздражении **взяла** олимпийца **«на слабо»**, и обязаны были молодые авторы участием мэтра в антологии.*

А вот что имеется в "Толковом словаре русской разговорной речи" (2021 г., [стр. **152**](https://ruslang.ru/sites/default/files/2022-03/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82.pdf)):

> PHRAS: ***на слабо́ взять** кого (сниж.)* — усомнившись в чьих-либо качествах, способностях и т. п., спровоцировать его на что-либо. *Знаете/ как во дворе
> или как среди мужчин бывает/ **взяли на слабо**/ то есть сказали/ вот вы будете трусом/ будешь трусом/ если не пойдешь на выборы*// (Р/с «Эхо Москвы», 2003–2004); *Молодая практикантка мальчишек **на слабо взяла**: сможете ночью дойти по глухому лесу до речки или не сможете?* (А. и С. Литвиновы. Мадонна без младенца).

То есть словарь относит это сочетание к фразеологизмам, а в них, как известно, кавычки не используются (сравните: *взять на понт, брать за жабры, брать на пушку, взять на карандаш*).

Я бы это ***устойчивое выражение*** (пусть даже и разговорно-сниженное) тоже написала без кавычек.

Answer (score 1):

**Дополнительный грамматический и информационный материал по теме**

1. **О грамматике**

**БРАТЬ,**  нсв. (св. взять). **7. что.** **Овладевать, захватывать; побеждать, выигрывать** (во время войны, политической борьбы, спортивного состязания, охоты и т.п.). Б. крепость, высотку. Б. укрепление штурмом, приступом, с боем. Б. власть, управление. Б. приз. Беру вашу пешку, карту (бью, забираю в свою пользу). Наша берёт! (разг.; одерживаем победу, одолеваем). Лисица рябчика берёт (ловит). * Смелость города берёт (Посл.). **8. чем.** **Добиваться своей цели,** применяя что-л., обладать всеми необходимыми качествами для достижения чего-л. Б. настойчивостью. Б. не числом, а умением. Б. терпеньем. Б. хитростью.

**Точного** управления нет. Тогда **сравним** с просторечным выражением: ***брать на испуг***

**[Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка](https://phraseology.academic.ru/547/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B3)**

**БРАТЬ НА ИСПУГ кого. ВЗЯТЬ НА ИСПУГ** кого. **Прост.** Пытаться смутить, запугать кого-либо в корыстных целях.  Немец отвязался, вышел. Тётя Маня ко мне: «Что он тут воевал?» «Да вот, — говорю, — **на испуг хотел взять** пан офицер» (В. Аксёнов. Комментарии к детству).

Итак, просторечный характер выражения объясняется отсутствием **нормативного управления**. Но кавычек все равно  нет, вероятно, они могут быть связаны со словом **"слабо".**

2. **О слове "слабо"**

**СЛАБО, в функц. сказ.** кому (что). **Разг.-сниж.** Не может кто-л., не хватает сил, умения, решительности у кого-л.; не под силу, невмочь (о возможности выполнить, сделать что-л. кем-л.). А с. тебе прыгнуть в высоту на два метра? А с. тебе спеть? С. со мной тягаться? Тебе с. машину купить. Брату с. в институт поступить.

**СЛАБО,** в знач. сказуемого: **слабО** тебе это сделать! Большой **орфоэпический** словарь русского языка.

**Вывод.** Кавычки не нужны для обозначения просторечия. Вероятно, их иногда ставили, чтобы обозначить второе значение ***"слабО"***, сравнить: ***слАбо.***

3. **Практика письма  Карта слов**

**Кавычек нет:**

Любого может **взять на слабо.**

Если бы ты не был идиотом, ты бы сначала поинтересовался кого решил взять на слабо.

И, увы, меня до сих пор легко **взять на слабо**. Что и подтвердилось…

4. **О словаре**

**[Толковый словарь русской разговорной речи](https://%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8)**

Толковый словарь русской разговорной речи. Вып. 5: У–Я / Авторы-составители: Е. И. Голанова, О. П. Ермакова, Е. Г. Жидкова, А. В. Занадворова, Е. В. Какорина, Л. П. Крысин, Е. А. Никишина, А. Р. Пестова, Н. Н. Розанова, Р. И. Розина, О. А. Шарыкина. — М. ; СПб. : Нестор-История, 2022. — 760 с.
1200 руб. по предзаказу

В словаре содержится описание лексики современной русской **разговорной речи.** Словарь имеет **экспериментальный** характер и, в отличие от большинства академических толковых словарей, **не является нормативным.** Задачей составителей было с возможной полнотой отразить в словарной форме семантические, грамматические, сочетаемостные, стилистические свойства лексических и фразеологических средств...

Comment: Прочитал ваш ответ, тоже плюс ставлю.

Comment: @Максим Спасибо! Я очень старалась добавить что-то новое) Плюс за ваш вопрос. Постановка кавычек вообще интересная тема, иногда найти и объяснить решение бывает не так просто.